# ffmpeg installation on windows 8 xampp v3.2.1 php 5.5.3

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp

I am trying to install ffmpeg extension on windows 8 xampp v3.2.1 for php 5.5.3.

I have files of ffmpeg and i am doing following steps

1. Placing file php_ffmpeg.dll in xampp/php/ext/
2. Rest files i am keeping in windows/system32
3. I have added extension=php_ffmpeg.dll in php.ini
4. Restarted xampp

but when i see php_info then my extension ffmpeg still not enabled.

I think ffmpeg files are not compatible to php 5.5.3. May be i have old files so will you please provide me new and correct ffmpeg files for php 5.5.3

or do you know why i am facing this problem? any solution for this